# Moving from Windows to Ubuntu. What programs to use?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation

Maby my question is not related to this forum, but I want to ask. I want to change my OS from Windows XP to Ubuntu 10.6. But I like some programs in Windows, so is there a GOOD programs in Linux(Ubuntu) to change this list of programs? And I'll be apprishiated for some links where I can download GOOD software for Linux. I need such programs, that I could open their files in Windows OS environment. For example: .doc, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .txt and others. Thanx!

Musical players: Aimp Winamp Sound forge

Kodecks for video, audio etc.

Microsoft Office 2003, Vizio, WinRAR, Adobe reader, Dejavju reader, Fine Reader, Adobe Photoshop, Paint, Nero, Alcohol 120%, DiamonTools, Far, Total Commander, Dreamveawer, Visual Studio 2005, Denwer

Messangers: QiP, ICQ, Skype

Browsers: Opera, Mozila

Antiviruses!! NOD32, Avast, Kaspersky?

Translators: Lingvo 12, Pragma

BitTorrent, Download Master.

Comment: A community wiki might be handier here?

Comment: You may wish to check this post [What are the most useful programs installed after setup of a Vanilla Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1237/what-are-the-most-useful-programs-installed-after-setup-of-a-vanilla-ubuntu)

Comment: Post closed Marco :(

Answer (score 11):

First of all, welcome to Ubuntu! :-)

So, all the software you mentioned in your list have an equivalent in Linux. I really suggest you spend time reading one of these links I offer you below:

- [Linux software equivalent to Windows software](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Linux_software_equivalent_to_Windows_software)
- [List of free and open source software packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages)
- List Of Open-source Programs (LOOP): [1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoopList/), [2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListOfOpenSourcePrograms#Linux)

I'm sure you will have great suggestions apart from those lists. It was there that I chose to use the following equivalents:

- gimp for images (.jpeg, .png, .gif)
- OpenOffice.org for create and manipulate Microsoft Office docs
- Telepathy for Messangers (QiP, ICQ, Msn, etc) with Skype available
- Mozila Firefox replacing Iternet Explorer

For all other software you have an equivalent in Ubuntu, and you can easily search and install using the tool [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter), see a screenshot below ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center)):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You would be able to open the **.doc, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .txt**  formats out of the box without any extra effort.
After you finish installing ubuntu on your computer you just have to run one command to get all the audio,video codecs and java, and flash.

**Microsoft Office 2003, WinRAR, Adobe reader, Adobe Photoshop, Paint, Nero, Dreamveawer, 
Nero** there are alternatives for these softwares but you can install them under a software called [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Nero has a native linux version.

**Messangers: QiP, ICQ, Skype**
Skype works nativaly and ICQ and Qip chat would be available under empathy messanger whick is default messanger of ubuntu.

**Browsers: Opera, Mozila**
Both of these browsers and Google chrome also work natively

for **bittorrent** you can use transmission which comes out of the box in ubuntu or Deluge which has utorrent like User interface.

**Some links to download softwares**

There is an **ubuntu software centre in ubuntu** just like Iphone appstore, but almost all the software there are free and as you are a new user you would find most of the sofware that you need in the software centre, so you dont need any links download software.

PS. I think I have given you enough reasons to switch into ubuntu :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, you shouldn't need to download apps from the web (at least most of the time) as the Ubuntu Software Centre, found under the **Applications** tab in the upper left of the screen, contains most of the applications you will need on Ubuntu, all for free. The Software Centre is divided into categories (Office, Web, Programming, etc) and all you have to do to install software from it is to hit the 'install' button and enter you user password, and you're all set.

Now, onto specific applications.

**Visual Studio**: If you're planning on doing development on Linux, you may want to check out the accepted answer to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux). The default text editor on Ubuntu has built in support for syntax highlighting of a great many languages and can have it's functionality expanded with plugins (many of which some preinstalled). If you're looking for an IDE for a particular language, then just search for that language in the Software Centre (you probably don't need to include 'IDE').

**Nero**: Fluendo is available from the Software Centre for $25 under the recently introduced 'for purchase' category.

**Adobe Reader**: Ubuntu has a built in pdf viewer called Evince.

**Alcohol 120%**: Ubuntu has a DVD burner called Brasero, though I'm not sure how it compares to Alcohol in terms of features.

**WinRAR**: Ubuntu has a built in archive manage that can handle .zip and .tar.gz. Though if you want to use WinRAR, I think there's a Linux version available.

**Total Commander**: Nautilus is Ubuntu's window manager. Play around with it and see if it has the features you use in Total Commander.

**Far**: Nautilus and Archive Manager, mentioned as possible alternatives elsewhere in this list, may be able to replace this, though I've never encountered Far before so I can't say for sure.

**Vizio**: I think Dia, found in the Software Centre, is what you're after there, though I've not used Vizio so I couldn't say how it compares.

**Adobe Photoshop**: The Gimp, available from the Software Centre, is the bext bitmap editor available on Linux, and Inkscape is available if you want to do some vector editing.

**Microsoft Office**: Open Office is the primary alternative to MS Office and is preinstalled in Ubuntu.

**BitTorrent**: Transmission is the torrent client preinstalled in Ubuntu

**Security**: ClamAV is a good anti-virus program, not preinstalled but found in the Software Centre. The Ubuntu firewall is good and so you won't need a third party program.

**Browsers**: Firefox comes preinstalled on Ubuntu

**Messengers**: Empathy is the preinstalled IM/IRC client on Ubuntu. It supports a wide range of services including MSN, Gtalk and Facebook Chat.

**Music players**: Rhythmbox is preinstalled on Ubuntu, although I personally use Banshee (available from the Software Centre) because of the increased functionality. If you're used to WinAmp, then you might like to check that one out.

**Codecs**: There are few preinstalled codecs on Ubuntu, but support for pretty much all AV filetypes is available from the Software Centre. Just search for 'Gstreamer' and you'll get a list of codecs that provide the support for a multitude of formats. Check them out and install the ones you want.

.txt files can be opened in Ubuntu's default text editor, Gedit, and the various images formats can be opened in the default image viewer.

I've done what I can here, though you're going to have to fire up Ubuntu and play around with it and see what it does for you. Remember, just search the Software Centre and see what you come across.

Answer (score 1):

When moving from WindowsXP to Ubuntu/GNOME you will find that from the usability of your desktop not very much may have changed. Still, you are now on a very different OS. This needs some **change of thinking** especially when it comes to applications and how to install them.

Unlike Windows you have not only installed a modern operating system with Ubuntu but much more: it's what we call a "**distribution**". This means that almost all useful **applications that are tested to run are already included** but perhaps not yet installed on your PC from the installation CD.

Running Applications that are not provided on CD is done with a **few mouse clicks only**. There are several programs installed that do this, but you will find the **Software Center** where you can choose from an overwhelming variety of tested, useful and mostly free software a good point to start.

Downloading files from other internet recources is rarely needed. In fact it is discouraged because those applications may not be tested, can cause instabilities to your system and cannot be updated automatically (which is otherwise the case).

Try out Ubuntu and you will soon find that thinking "the Ubuntu way" is what you have always missed in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Musical players: Aimp Winamp Sound forge
VLC, Banshee, Rhythmbox, even Winamp itself (using playonlinux); all available in the software center.

**Codecs** for video, audio etc. - if you choose install extras during your install *(maverick, 10.10, and later) you don't have to install these. To be sure, install ubuntu-restricted-addons and -extras (using software center, or synaptic).

Microsoft Office 2003,
Open Office works fine with files from Office 2003, but if you are really really looking for the exact thing, use PlayOnLinux to give you an easy install. (It's in the ubuntu-software center)

Vizio,
Try Dia.

WinRAR,
So long as you install rar and unrar, you will get support for rar files in Archive Manager that comes with ubuntu.

Adobe reader,
Ubuntu can open PDF's by default, and you can also install Adobe Reader if you enable the partner repo in software center.

Dejavju reader,
Is in software center.

Fine Reader,
Not sure what that is.

Adobe Photoshop,
Try GIMP (in software center), or GIMPShop.

Paint,
Try [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/).

Nero
Ubuntu comes with Brasero, but you can also try K3B (software center).
Alcohol 120%
There are various applications in the software center that do the same job, but brasero can create iso files, so basically you can use it to backup CD/DVD media.

DiamonTools,
GMountIso, AcetoneISO, etc.\

Far,
Not sure what that is

Total Commander,
Nautilus should be powerful enough.

Dreamveawer, Visual Studio 2005, Denwer
Bluefish, Monodevelop, not sure what the 3rd is, but there are many alternatives in software center.

Messangers: QiP, ICQ, Skype
Empathy, Pidgin, Skype. See the software center :D.

Browsers: Opera, Mozila
Firefox is included, Opera is available for ubuntu.

Antiviruses!! NOD32, Avast, Kaspersky?
Ubuntu doesn't really need an antivirus program, but you coudld use a firewall user-interface such as Guard Dog or Gufw, to add some rules to the built in firewall.

Translators: Lingvo 12, Pragma
There are some translation applications in the software center, but this is not a field I can expand on much.

Answer (score 0):

Musical players: Personally I use Banshee, but it is more iTunes like than winamp. There is a lot of different players out there, like Guayadeque, Clementine, Amarok and Rhythmbox (which is bundled with Ubuntu). Maybe you would like to check out [DeaDBeeF](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/).

Kodecks: If you install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package, you should have all the stuff you need, including flash and java.

The apps i know of:

Microsoft Office 2003: OpenOffice.org is bundled with Ubuntu.

WinRAR: Already present. Rar files can be opened by installing the package `rar`.

Adobe reader: Replacement is already there, though you can install Adobe Reader too. I like the default better though.

Dejavju reader: Install `libdjvulibre21` to make the document opener support djvu files.

Adobe Photoshop: GIMP.

Paint: I use GIMP for the most, it's not as slow as PS. You could try out [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/download) though.

Nero: Brasero is bundled.

Alcohol 120%: Mounting is supported by default. For more advanced stuff you could try out `acetoneiso` or `gisomount`.

Total Commander: I use FileZilla for FTP.

Dreamveawer: Bluefish is a good bet.

Visual Studio 2005: See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/visual-studio-style-tool).

Messangers: Empathy is installed by default. Another good multi-protocol messenger is Pidgin. Skype can be installed from the software center.

Browsers: All of them are available native.

Antiviruses: You could install ClamAv, but it is only detecting windows viruses. You really don't need antivirus on linux (one of the great advantages).

Translators: I don't really know anything here.

BitTorrent: Transmission gets the job done for me. Otherwise there's Deluge and a lot of other clients.