# Visual Studio alternatives for ubuntu?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio style tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/visual-studio-style-tool)

Are there any alternative c++ IDEs like Microsoft's Visual Studio on ubuntu?

Comment: the most likely would be Qt SDK