# .Net and Visual Studio in Ubuntu?

Tags: ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio style tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/visual-studio-style-tool)

I want to run .Net in my Ubuntu, is there is way for this and as all know that .Net is famous for its IDE(Visual Studio), is that possible or there are other IDE for the replacement of Visual Studio in the open Source community, if so, how do i install it?