# Developer tools

Tags: workspaces

I am pretty new to the world of Ubuntu, heard so many great things about it, I decided to test the waters. Since I have it installed on a partition of my MacBook, I thought it would be a good idea to set it up as a portable workstation, for my courses all my programming professors use Windows, so that is my desktop setup with Visual Studio and Aptana. What is your set up like? What developer tools do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/is-there-a-visual-studio-style-tool-ide

Comment: Hi N3L5ONMD and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a Q/A site, not a forum, so we don't do open-ended discussions, polls, etc. I suggest you ask on the Ubuntu forums or Ubuntu discourse. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies @Seth I shall keep that in mind, I do not want to start on the wrong foot here. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C and C++ I'm using Codeblocks.

```
sudo apt install codeblocks
```

For Java and PHP I'm using Eclipse and NetBeans.

I really support codeblocks. I think codeblocks is really useful and simple and enough for C and C++ projects.