# WPF programming in ubuntu

Tags: c#

I want to work c# WPF. i search the net and find MonoDevelop ,
I want to know that is there any IDE for WPF in Ubuntu.
and is that powerful as Visual studio in windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/6588/is-there-a-visual-studio-style-tool-ide ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you will not be able to find a IDE for .NET in linux that is as powerful as Visual Studio. I am using MonoDevelop, which is quite decent IDE. I have problems when debugging because watching variable does not always work, but other than that it works as expected.

Regarding WPF, I believe you cannot do it in Linux. You must be aware that Mono, which works great in Linux, is a subset of .NET and will probably never support everything that is available in Windows. I was surprised that so many things work, which I didn't expect too. Take a look here for WPF: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you can use [Avalonia UI Framework](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) which is not the same thing but similar. [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/) has no plan for adopting WPF or UWP. C# do support OpenTK(OpenGL) or Gtk#(GUI) through wrappers. WinForms is supported in Mono.

You may even try WINE given valve/steam tried so hard to bring there games to Linux and instead settled with Proton which is technically WINE for games. That way you only have to maintain a wine-optimized windows binary.

Answer (score 0):

[Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/?_ga=2.165724343.806808502.1570108983-1619074503.1570108983) has a [XAML preview tool](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/03/29/xaml-preview-tool-window-wpf-rider/), but you can't edit the properties or animations with it visually, like with Blend for Visual Studio.