# Is there any native C#/C++ IDE similar to Visual Studio but more lightweight in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, c++, ide, c#

I was using Visual Studio for two years in Windows, but now I am using Ubuntu. Are there any other C#/C++ IDEs to use that are as high quality as Visual Studio? Please don't tell me the name of another IDE that tells me to download 5 GB of files before I can even test it, and then I'm supposed to try to run the whole thing with Wine. I want to use it in Ubuntu as an application for Linux, not install a Windows application in Ubuntu with Wine.

Comment: What language are you developing in?  Did you look at eclipse?

Comment: C# , C++ @ubfan1

Comment: What exactly is wrong with Visual Studio Code? It's apparently what you're looking for. If you want other IDEs, there are also plenty to choose from. However, your question is then too broad and opinion based for this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Visual Studio style tool/IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6588/507051)

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Code will show up in Ubuntu Software application if you search for "vscode" or it can be installed from the terminal by running the command `sudo snap install code --classic` A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Visual Studio Code extensions are installed into the user's home directory.

Visual Studio Code is not an full featured IDE. For this reason it is not possible to create a project in Visual Studio Code, like it is in Visual Studio. On the other hand it is possible to run Python, C, C++, JavaScript, PHP, Java, R and some other programming language code blocks directly in Visual Studio Code using the Code Runner extension. It is also possible to run HTML code in an external web browser using the open in browser extension. Visual Studio Code is a lot smaller than Microsoft Visual Studio, however many Visual Studio extensions can also be installed in Visual Studio Code by selecting *View* -> *Extensions* and then search for the extension that you want to install.

---

C# is open source and cross platform now that Microsoft has released a version of .NET Core. To install .NET Core in Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet # to run dotnet-sdk type dotnet
```

Run these commands to build and run an example C# Hello World console app from the terminal:

```
cd ~
mkdir C#_Projects
cd C#_Projects
mkdir HelloWorld
cd HelloWorld
dotnet new console
dotnet build --output ./build_output  
dotnet ./build_output/HelloWorld.dll
```

Results of `dotnet ./build_output/HelloWorld.dll`

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: am looking for IDE like visual studio and working with c#  @karel